# Performing a chi-quare test in Python 3 to test normality

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, scipy, chi-squared

I got the following file:

[image: file]

I want to test normality of this dataset. 
I want to do this via a chisquare test.

I performed it in excel, and I get the following results (which I want to achieve in Python):

```
chisquare = 5.53
p-value = 0.14
```

The formulas how I did it in excel is as follows:

I first calculated the z-value for every value in each column. 
I then calculated the expected values below -1, between -1 and 0, between 0 and 1 and bigger than +1, based on the standard normal distribution (n(0,1)). I then calculated the real values (based on the z-values) in these ranges.

I could then calculate chi-squared values for each range by (observed values-expected values)^2/expected values.

The chi-squared values are summed and this gives 5.53.
Because I used 4 ranges, I used 3 degrees of freedom. 5.53 and 3 degrees of freedom gives a p-value of 0.14 (formula is called CHIDIST(chi-squared value, degrees of freedom).

The question is: how can I perform this calculation in Python and do it with multiple rows?

Comment: FYI: It does not appear to be relevant in the code that you show, but you really shouldn't use `import numpy as pd`.  I hope that using `pd` there was just a mistake made while typing the question.

Comment: *"... as I perform it in excel"*  Show the formula or functions that you used in Excel.

Comment: *"I want to test normality of this dataset."*  FYI: The simple chi-squared test `chisquare(x)` does not test for normality.  [`chisquare`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) expects the first parameter `f_obs` to be an array of "frequencies" (i.e. number of occurrences of various categories).  If you don't provide the second parameter `f_exp`, the test assumes that you are comparing the given frequencies to the case where each category is equally likely.

Comment: I made some edits. I also want to know then how can I calculate expected values when want to test normality

Comment: That's why I want to be able to do it in Python, as I am asking here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick spreadsheet to test the values and it looks like

```
a,b,c 
1,2,3
```

Then, with Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')  # above
df.iloc[:, 1:].values
> array([[2, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

But that's a nested array. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) for `chisquare` suggest a flattened array, so you may want to try

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].values.flatten()
> array([2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I'm looking at it, but how is df.iloc[:, 1:].values from df.iloc[:, 1:].values ?

Comment: That was a typo. I forgot to add the `.flatten()` part at the end, which flattens the result.

Comment: thanks. Gives indeed a result, but the chi square result is >13.000 and the p-value = 0.0. I still seem to do something wrong...any idea?

Comment: It's difficult to say without comparing to your Excel function. The chisquare test has a few different [variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Other_examples_of_chi-squared_tests) that Excel/Scipy may differ on. It could also vary quite a bit depending on whether one of the implementations secretly changes the degrees of freedom or the expected values.